# How to compose XCM call, which sends xcm message from a normal account on relay to a normal account on parachain(1000), and executes encoded call?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, xcmp, xcmv3

I am attempting to compose an XCM call that sends a message  from the relay chain to AssetHub, from one normal account (on Rococo) to the same normal account (on AH), and then executes a call.

Once it has reached that account it will use Transact to execute an encoded call, which is to mint some asset for: asset_id 57, amount: 999,999,999,999, dest: Alice.

The normal account is the owner of the asset and has the authority to mint this asset.

The Transact part i think is pretty simple, its just an encoded call.
However how do you curate the rest?

For MultiLocation: I imagine it is `X1` and `AccountId32` to `0x10b44f78c2668684521fda94a1cd6b9d4035156e8c073018d0d59e4aa8cca01b`

DescendOrigin, BuyExecution and WithdrawAsset, i am not sure of...

where's the best place to learn about composing XCM calls?

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples of using `Transact` and other XCM primitives at the docs https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/journey/transact.html

Usually if using `Transact`, you want to also use it with `BuyExecution` and `WithdrawAsset`. Here's an example from the docs:

```rust
let call = parachain::RuntimeCall::Balances(
    pallet_balances::Call::<parachain::Runtime>::set_balance {
        who: ALICE,
        new_free: 5 * AMOUNT,
        new_reserved: 0,
    },
);

let message = Xcm(vec![
    WithdrawAsset((Here, AMOUNT).into()),
    BuyExecution { fees: (Here, AMOUNT).into(), weight_limit: WeightLimit::Unlimited },
    Transact {
        origin_kind: OriginKind::Superuser,
        require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(INITIAL_BALANCE as u64, 1024 * 1024),
        call: call.encode().into(),
    },
]);
```